# PlanetScope NDWI calculations

Tags: arcgis-pro, planet, reflectance, normalized-difference-water-index

I am trying to calculate NDWI for a PlanetScope image scene. I currently have 2 products: one is the "3B_AnalyticMS_SR.tif" and the other is the "3B_AnalyticMS.tif" product. I believe the former is the surface reflectance, and the latter is the TOA radiance.

My problem is that I tried to calculate NDWI using the surface reflectance product, only to get NDWI values all below 0.3, but I know there should be values above 0.3 since there's water. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Snippets of the two imagery products can be found [here.](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/170belXJ-df-mSDNKBLpf99ztMli6_izx?usp=sharing)

To calculate the NDWI, I took the "3B_AnalyticMS_SR.tif" product and used the ArcGIS Pro band arithmetic function to calculate the NDWI equation (B2-B4)/(B2+B4). This has worked previously for me in calculating NDWI, so I am convinced my issue is with the data I am using. I have found documentation saying the SR product is surface reflectance, but I also found information detailing that it is scaled radiance as well.

Comment: Can you contact the data supplier to confirm that your rasters really are surface reflectance and TOA?  Without confirmation, *all* results, reasonable or otherwise, will be suspect.

Answer (score 0):

You calculate the Normalized Difference Water Index (NDWI) from multi-spectral satellite data, such as Landsat. If you look at this [page](https://www.bluemarblegeo.com/knowledgebase/global-mapper-19/Raster_Calculator.htm) it states you are using the green and Near-Infrared bands to compute the index.

If you look at the statistics of these bands in your dataset they are all large integers. You need to rescale the values, this is in the metadata which you had provided in your sample dataset, suggest you revisit that.